# Android AVD: Not starting OS, Black Screen Only

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I formatted my PC, installed Windows 10, SDK and installed API 15 and 23 with build tools. After importing my application into Android Studio I created a new AVD, please see screenshot.

[image: Screenshot - AVD Settings]

I did not enable `Use host GPU` and the RAM is set to 1GB, with the HAXM RAM set to 2GB. I double checked the BIOS and Virtualization Settings are enabled. I have run the emulator from the command line using the following command:

`emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_15 -netspeed full -netdelay none -debug-init -logcat '*:v'`

There were no errors but it does seem to hang at:

`emulator: UpdateChecker: skipped version check`

I am currently quite frustrated and not sure how to resolve this issue. Can anyone please help.

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: go to "AndroidSDK\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/" find intelhaxm-android.exe and run this setup may this can help.

Comment: I have done and restarted pc after reinstall of haxm and still no t resolve

Comment: Same problem here on Mac OS X, without Host GPU enabled the emulator remains Black (with Host GPU enabled, it randomly freezes)

Answer (score 1):

The first time you start the avd it always take a lot of time (could be a couple of minutes), did you close the avd too early?

Comment: No, I waited nearly an hour and it still did not start the OS (Black Screen only)